# print with shell_exec on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, shell-exec

Hi would use shell_exec for direct print a PDF file.
My code is:

```
<?php
shell_exec( 'print /d:"EPSON MFC-J265W" c:\file.txt');
?>
```

When i try to run this code i receive this error:

**Unable to initialize the device Epson**

Comment: don't create multiple questions for each error message you get, but add the errors in comments in your current question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet you need to put it in quotes.

```
<?php
shell_exec( 'print /d:"EPSON MFC-J265W" c:\file.txt');
?>
```

Ultimately, you should test this on the command line to see what actually needs done.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found a workaround!

```
$updateCommand = "w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:\\\"".$timeServers."\\\" /update";

$updateCommandCmd = 'cmd /c " '.$updateCommand.' "';

$updateResult = shell_exec($updateCommandCmd);
```

using cmd /c and escaping both \ and " creating something like

```
cmd /c " w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:\"0.europe.pool.ntp.org 1.europe.pool.ntp.org\" /update "
```

does the trick on windows 7 ONLY (sorry)